# Grouping connected pairs of values

Tags: algorithm, grouping

I have a list containing unique pairs of values **x** and **y**; for example:

```
x      y
--     --
1      A
2      A
3      A
4      B
5      A
5      C
6      D
7      D
8      C
8      E
9      B
9      F
10     C
10     G
```

I want to divide this list of pairs as follows:

```
Group 1
1      A
2      A
3      A
5      A
5      C
8      C
10     C
8      E
10     G

Group 2
4      B
9      B
9      F

Group 3
6      D
7      D
```

Group 1 contains

- all pairs where **y** = 'A' (1-A, 2-A, 3-A, 5-A)
- any additional pairs where **x** = any of the **x**'s above (5-C)
- any additional pairs where **y** = any of the **y**'s above (8-C, 10-C)
- any additional pairs where **x** = any of the **x**'s above (8-E, 10-G)

The pairs in Group 2 can't be reached in such a manner from any pairs in Group 1, nor can the pairs in Group 3 be reached from either Group 1 or Group 2.

As suggested in Group 1, the chain of connections can be arbitrarily long.

I'm exploring solutions using Perl, but any sort of algorithm, including pseudocode, would be fine. For simplicity, assume that all of the data can fit in data structures in memory.

**[UPDATE]** Because I need to apply this approach to 5.3 billion pairs, scaleability is important to me.

Comment: This appears to be a simple graph connectivity problem; where are you stuck with turning this into an algorithm?  You seem to have it well in hand.

Comment: I don't know anything about graph theory. I thought there might be a simpler way than making repeated "sweeps". Thanks for your solution!

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a starting point.  Find all points reachable from that, removing from the master list.  Repeat for all added points, until no more can be reached.  Move to the next group, starting with another remaining point.  Continue until you have no more remaining points.

```
pool = [(1 A), (2 A), (3 A), (4 B), ... (10 G)]
group_list = []
group = []
pos = 0

while pool is not empty
    group = [ pool[0] ]   # start with next available point
    pos = -1

    while pos+1 < size(group)  // while there are new points in the group
        pos += 1
        group_point = group[pos]    // grab next available point
        for point in pool           // find all remaining points reachable
            if point and group_point have a coordinate in common
                remove point from pool
                add point to group

    // we've reached closure with that starting point
    add group to group_list

return group_list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the letters and numbers as nodes of a graph, and the pairs as edges. Divide this graph into connected components in linear time.

The connected component with 'A' forms group 1. The other connected components form the other groups.

Comment: I don't know what that means, since I don't know graph theory. However, the phrase "linear time" leaps out, because although prune's algorithm works, it doesn't appear to run in linear time. If you can sketch up your algorithm I'd like to consider it.

Comment: @Chap To find a connected component, pick a vertex and run either breadth-first-search (BFS) or depth-first-search (DFS) from it. Either of these will reach exactly the vertices connected to your starting vertex. These are good algorithms to know, and you can find good write-ups of them on Wikipedia.